# Duplicate output from princ / pp?

Tags: eval, print

So I'm trying to figure out why the following produces unexpected output:

```
(setq var 1)
(pp var)
(princ var)
```

Put the cursor just after the closing `)` in the expression `(setq var 1)` and then press C-xC-e to evaluate it.  I see the following in the echo area: `1 (#o1 #x1 ?\C-a)`.  I think this makes sense - it's just listing the number 1 several different ways.

I go on to evaluate (C-xC-e again) `(pp var)` and then see the following: `1"1"`

**Why do I see the 1 twice?**

**Why is it listed inside the double-quotes the second time**

Likewise, when I go on to evaluate (C-xC-e) `(princ var)` and then see the following: `11 (#o1 #x1 ?\C-a)`

**Why is there an 11 at the start?**  I'm guessing that it's printing the value 1 twice, right next to each other (instead of printing the number 11), but why is it printing `1` twice?

Comment: Please always state clearly how you are *"evaluating"* something. As @xuchunyang's answer says, you are no doubt not *just* evaluating the sexp. You are also printing its value, and the result of your command is being echoed.

Comment: Whoops - sorry, I didn't know that would be an important detail.  Is specifying C-xC-e (like I did above) clear?

Comment: Yes, as the accepted answer indicates. What you see is not due to just evaluation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Evaluating`(princ 1)` with `C-x C-e` (`eval-last-sexp`) displays the following in the echo area

```
11 (#o1 #x1 ?\C-a)
```

because `(princ 1)` prints `1` and returns the integer `1`. And `(pp 1)` is the same as `(princ "1")`, it prints `1` and returns the string `"1"`.

---

Try executing them in `M-x ielm`, it produces cleaner output.

```
*** Welcome to IELM ***  Type (describe-mode) for help.
ELISP> (setq var 1)
1 (#b1, #o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP> (pp var)
1
"1"
ELISP> (princ var)
1
1 (#b1, #o1, #x1, ?\C-a)
ELISP>
```